# SQL get Parent where Children have specific values

Tags: sql, join

Given is a `Parent` with the field `id` and `Child` relation with `parent_id` and `name`. How would a query look like to get all `Parents` which have two children, one with the name 'John' and one with the name 'Mike'. My problem is, that I am not able to build a query which returns the Parents having both children. I used `Where IN ('John', 'Mike')` so I get also the Parents returned which have also one child with the name 'John' or 'Mike'. But I want only the Parents with both children only.

```
SELECT * FROM Parent
JOIN Child ON Child.parent_id = Parent.id
WHERE Child.name IN ('John', 'Mike')
```

My query is of course more complex and this is only an abstraction for what I want to achieve. I have in mind, that I first need to join the children on parent_id and make something with that, but no idea.

Comment: Please specify the database engine you are working with, for example SQL Server, MySQL, etc.

Comment: why not use `WHERE Child.name = "John" AND WHERE Child.name = "Mike"; `

Comment: @AndreyKaplun I don't think that is valid syntax.

Comment: Because the Child can not have both names ;) I want ANSI SQL, will take it as a base to build a query for Ecto.

Comment: @dfundako it will depend on the database engine

Comment: @AndreyKaplun Which DB engine allows 'WHERE condition AND WHERE condition2'?

Comment: @dfundako sql server mysql

Comment: @AndreyKaplun I can assure you SQL Server does not allow you do put WHERE condition1 AND WHERE condition2. The 2nd WHERE keyword throws an error. And as Sardoan mentioned, a name cannot be two different values at the same time.

Comment: it can try it @dfundako

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do two joins and look for your specific records. This example shows that parent 1 will return with both kiddos, but not parent 2 that only has a Mike.

```
DECLARE @parent TABLE (ID INT)
DECLARE @child TABLE (ID INT, parentID INT, name VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @parent 
VALUES 
(1),
(2),
(3),
(4),
(5),
(6)

INSERT INTO @child (ID, parentID, name)
VALUES 
(1, 1, 'Mike'),
(2, 1, 'John'),
(3, 2, 'Mike'),
(4, 2, 'Bill'),
(5, 3, 'Dave'),
(6, 4, 'Sam')

SELECT p.*

FROM @parent p

INNER JOIN @child c1
    ON c1.parentID = p.id
    AND c1.name = 'Mike'

INNER JOIN @child c2
    ON c2.parentID = p.ID
    AND c2.name = 'John'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try having two steps in the where clause.  Both conditions will have to be true to return a parent record.

```
where parent.id in (select parent_id from child where child.name='John')
and parent.id in (select parent_id from child where child.name='Mike')
```

Comment: The two joins and the two subselects look good. Will try both. Thanks.

Comment: @Sardoan I would recommend you check out the execution plan when implementing both and see which is more performant for your live data based on reads and execution time.

Answer (score 0):

something like this would work in postgres if you have having.

```
SELECT parent_id, SUM(num) FROM (
  SELECT parent_id, 1 as num FROM Child Where name = 'John'
  UNION
  SELECT parent_id, 1 as num FROM Child Where name = 'Mike'
) parents 
GROUP BY parent_id HAVING SUM(num) = 2
```

Comment: This could potentially find a parent of two children who are both named John. Seems unlikely, but possible :)

Answer (score 0):

So,
added the solution with the double join into an Ecto query and it passed my tests :)

```
from c in Child,
join: p in Parent, on: c.parent_id = p.id,
join: cc in Child, on: p.id = cc.parent_id,
where: c.name == ^"John",
where: cc.name == ^"Mike"
select: count(p.id)
```

Thanks for the ideas and the fast help :)